# Android activity - Back not working properly after pressing home

Tags: java, android, android-activity

If I have Activity A and Launch Activity B from it, then press home I go back to home screen.  If I launch the activity again from the recent apps, it goes back to B as it should, but when back is pressed the Activity send me back to the Home screen not Activity A.  Activity A and be are alive for the entire time.  How can I make the back button function as expected?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `finish()` on Activity A if you want the back button to go from Activity B to Activity A...

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the Home button empties the Activity stack.

You can capture the Back button and make it do what you want, but you would have to implement your own stack of previous activities.

Comment: Normaly I would do this, but the second activity is an external jar that I cannot edit.